# restrict array string value using typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want an array that allow only for the value of 'john' and 'james', both are not required, I tried below interface:

```
interface User {
  name: ['john' | 'james']
}
```

but it doesn't work for

```
const user: User = ['john', 'james']
```

it work only

```
const user: User = ['john']
const user: User = ['james']
```

I think I missed something

Comment: That interface does not work for any of your examples. None of your variables have the `name` property that is required by the interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typed an array with exactly one element that can either be `john` or `james`. If you want to allow multiple elements, you will need to do:

```
interface User {
  name: ('john' | 'james')[]
}
```

Now all the following are valid:

```
const u1: User = {
  name: ['john']
};

const u2: User = {
  name: ['james']
};

const u3: User = {
  name: ['john', 'james']
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use of an interface is not mandatory, you can take advantage of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```js
type User = 'john' | 'james';

const user1:User[] = ['john', 'james', 'jane'];
// ----------------------------------> ~~~~~~
//                                     Type '"jane"' is not assignable to type 'User'.(2322)

const user2:User[] = ['john', 'james', 'james']; // No errors
```